# How can I validate text box for telephone Number in windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if(textBox1.TextLength !=10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Telephone No Please check it again",
                    "ERROR",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

I try this code for validate text box for telephone number in c# .I assume that user must enter 10 numbers.But this didn't work correctly. This code allows digits and also characters. How can I validate text box that allows only 10 digits & only digits.

Comment: so what is wrong with this? do you only want to check the length?

Comment: You should probably use a regular expression with the following pattern: `"^\d{10}$"` or use a masked textbox instead of a regular textbox.

Comment: Define didn't work correctly

Comment: This code allow  any 10 characters or digits.But  telephone number only include digits.that's why I said it **didn't work correctly**.I want to write this code as only allows 10 digits & only digits.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simplistic approach... To make sure the text box contains exactly 10 digits and only digits... Then one possible solution is to capture each key the user enters into the text box. If the key pressed is NOT a digit or a backspace, then simply ignore this key. Capturing only digit keys can be accomplished using the text boxes `KeyPressed` event like below. The code below also only allows 10 digits. If more than 10 digits are entered, they are simply ignored.

```
private void txtPhoneNumber_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != (char)(Keys.Back))) { 
    e.Handled = true;
  }
  else {
    // is a digit or backspace - ignore digits if length is alreay 10 - allow backspace
    if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) {
      if (txtPhoneNumber.Text.Length > 9) {
        e.Handled = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only other possible problem may come when the user enters 1 or more digits but LESS than 10 digits and tries to LEAVE the text box by clicking on another control. Here we need to wire up the text boxes `Leave` event. If the user tries to leave the textbox before entering exactly ten digits, the code below will prompt the user that the phone number is not ten digits, then set the focus BACK to the phone number text box. The user can clear the text and continue if necessary, but the user will not be able to enter nine or less digits and leave the phone number text box.  Hope this helps.

```
private void txtPhoneNumber_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if ((txtPhoneNumber.Text.Length < 10) && (txtPhoneNumber.Text.Length > 0)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Phone number must be 10 digits!");
    txtPhoneNumber.Focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: can I use these two events to validate one text box ?

Comment: Yes. The posted code uses ONE `TextBox` named `txtPhoneNumber`. In fact without both events ... it wont work as described.

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(TextBox.Text,@"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}");

int noOfMatches = mc.Count;

if(mc>0)
{
valid condtion logic
}
else
{not valid logic
}
```